# Is docker phasing out some sites and services or something?

Tags: docker

**Aim:** to deploy a private registry

**Discussion**

*private repository*

I have read multiple posts and now I am confused. I have tried to run a docker container that should serve a private docker registry, but it returns an empty UI. Some posts indicate that it has been deprecated, but some other do not.

*images*

I used to navigate to dockerhub, but now there is https://store.docker.com?

**Questions**

1. Has docker registry been phased out?
2. Should one now use https://store.docker.com in stead of docker hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker hub still exists and will remain for the open source projects as it always has.

Docker store is a new offering for commercial images.

The standalone registry does not have a UI, don't believe it ever has. It's intended to be accessed with `docker push` and `docker pull` commands.